# OneToMany related entity not updating with preUpdate listener

Tags: symfony

I have set up an event listener with a preUpdate function, and I am trying to use this to update an address entity related through a OneToMany relationship. The function runs, and the object is updated, but this is not then persisted tot he database.

You can see the code below, does anyone have any ideas?

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args){
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Company) {

            $key = 0;
            $areaCode = explode(' ', $this->parsePostcode($entity->getAddresses()[$key]->getPostCode() ));
            $geo = $entityManager->getRepository('AlphaRMSBundle:SelGeo')->findOneByPostcode($areaCode[0]);


            if ($geo instanceof SelGeo) {
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setEastings($geo->getEastings());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setNorthings($geo->getNorthings());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setLatitude($geo->getLatitude());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setLongitude($geo->getLongitude());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setMunicipality($geo->getTownCity());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setRegion($geo->getRegion());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setCountry($geo->getCountryString());
                $entity->getAddresses()[$key]->setCountryUkCode($geo->getCountryUkCode());
                //die($entity->getAddresses()[$key]->getMunicipality());
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have solved this by acting on the Address entity directly, rather than the Company entity.